# stopping ios5 lifecycle events automatically being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5

All of my view controllers extend my own BaseViewController : UIViewController, and in this i have overridden

```
- (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
    return NO;
}
```

However, iOS 5 simulator has decided to ignore this and continues to call my viewWillAppear etc methods on my nested UIViewController hierarchy.

I've done the same in another project and it worked fine. Is there something else i'm missing to get it to listen to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you also have to use this method too:

```
UIViewController addChildViewController
```

So by doing this:

```
[self addChildViewController:_browserViewController];
[browserView addSubview:_browserViewController.view];
[_browserViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

..and returning NO from automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers

... it stops the view lifecycle methods being called twice.

Comment: So what's the solution to make something that works in both iOS 4 and 5

Comment: Well, if you're running iOS 4 - you won't get the automatic calls to your nested view controllers - so you don't have the issue of things being called twice. UIViewController container hierarchy was only introduced in iOS 5. You iOS 4 apps should just work as they always did. Just watch out for calling undefined selectors that are new to later iOS versions.

Comment: So the answer is that you have to ask if the instance can respond to the `-addChildViewController:` and `-didMoveToParentViewController:` methods before calling them?

Comment: You would think so, but interestingly ...no!! I'm using this and running my app on an iPad 1 with 4.3.5. When I debug and try and step into this, GDB just ignores me. My guess is that this method is already defined as a private method in 4.3.5 and it just does nothing. If anyone else can shed any light on this, I'd like to know why. But usually, yes I would check if it responds to selector. Usually I have a BaseViewController in all my projects - so I'd put it in here and call [super addChild ... if it responds....